# Handle trusted and untrusted domains in Freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch, trusted-vs-untrusted, fusionpbx

I have configured a Freeswitch system with a FusionPBX GUI. One of the requiremenmts i need to fulfill is to tell trusted domains apart from untrusted domains.

What I want to do is to make sure the P-Asserted-Identity field on the SIP Header is only sent to trusted domains and the From:field in a call would appear as anonymous@anonymous.invalid in case the call is made to a untrusted domain.

Here's the XML code I've made, but is not workingn (i have no idea why):

```
<extension name="call_privacy" >
   <condition field="destination_number" expression="^(210301\d\d\d)$" />
   <condition field="caller_id_number" expression="^(21030010\d)$" >
       <action application="set" data="sip_h_Privacy=id" />
       <action application="privacy" data="full" />
       <action application="set" data="privacy=yes" />
       <action application="transfer" data="$1 XML ${context}" />
       <action application="${sip_from_uri}" data="anonymous" />
   </condition>
</extension>
```

Can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think FusionPBX is flexible enough to handle this. It's quite easy to implement in FreeSWITCTH XML dialplan: the condition would determine the remote domain, and actions would set the asserted identity and caller ID.

Also I hope this short tutorial will be useful: https://github.com/voxserv/freeswitch_conf_minimal/blob/master/docs/tutorial_01_simple_pbx.md